# How to mock http.NewRequest to return an error

Tags: unit-testing, http, go

I have a Go method that makes an http request to an external web page, that I am screen scraping.  I have unit tests for when everything works as planned.  I can mock the httpclient and set the response to a predefined value.  However, I am having trouble creating tests for when things don't work.  I want to mock http.NewRequest to return an error.

I am using httptest and go tool cover.

Method to test:

```
func (cli *Client) GetSomething(sometext string) (string, error) {

    searchURL := strings.Replace(someUrl, "{PERSON_NAME}", url.QueryEscape(sometext), 1)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", someUrl, nil)
    if err != nil {
    // I want to test this scenario
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "failed to build request")
    }

    resp, err := cli.HTTPClient.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "request failed")
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    document, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    value:= document.Find(".someclass").Text()

    return value, nil
}
```

Test Method works for the httpclient.  Not sure how to mock http.NewRequest to return an error.  This would probably never happen, but just to be complete and as an exercise.

```
func TestGetSomethingFailedReqest(t *testing.T) {

    h := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        panic("Create error")
    })

//TestingHTTPClient is a helper function to create an HTTPClient.  Not needed for this test.

    httpClient, teardown := test.TestingHTTPClient(h)  
    defer teardown()
    scraperClient := NewClient()
    scraperClient.HTTPClient = httpClient

    var person= "John Doe"

    _, err := scraperClient.GetSomething(person)

    assert.Regexp(t, ".*failed to build request", err.Error())
}
```

Comment: Malformed URLs should produce an error, or URLs with a scheme other than http or https.

Comment: Yep. Pretty much the only way [`NewRequest`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=26884:26953#L802) can fail is if you pass an invalid URL, or an "invalid" (not just blank, it will default to GET) method. The latter is a whole separate problem because according to the spec, [non-standard methods are permitted](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1).

Comment: Or just use `"*?"` as request method. This should return `net/http: invalid method "*?"` error.

Comment: In case you can't change the request method, you can also pass `string([]byte{0x7f})` as the URL; this will result in a `parse "\u007f": net/url: invalid control character in URL` error.

Comment: I would have added a method to create new requests to `cli.HTTPClient` so i can write `cli.NewRequest` or `cli.HTTPClient.NewRequest` than just replace that wherever i need to fake the behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you want your tests to be reliable you should try to avoid mocking as much as you can.

So if you are wondering how you can test a library that is creating http request, the best way is to create a local server in your unit test, this way you can test every aspects of the request.

The best example I can provide you is this: https://github.com/gojek/heimdall/blob/master/httpclient/client_test.go
In Heimdall an open source http client, you can see how they implemented the tests without mocks.

And for your specific question, BentCoder replied to you: "just use "*?" as request method. This should return `net/http: invalid method "*?" error.`"

Answer (score 0):

Jeremie's answer regarding the specific question is correct, but the request method could be hardcoded.

The way http code is usually tested is by parameterising the url sent, so that it can be replaced in tests with a fake server.

Here's a trick for that scenario: require the url parameter to contain a trailing slash, and omit it in the test.

```golang
func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello")
    }))
    
    err := codeToTest(ts.URL + "/")
    fmt.Println(err) // Works!
    
    err = codeToTest(ts.URL) // <- no "/" at end of URL
    fmt.Println(err) // Fails!
}

func codeToTest(url string) error {
    _, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%vendpoint", url), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Go playground**

https://play.golang.org/p/JQBudQPthdE

Comment: to test an http handler you, probably, never need a test server

Comment: @mh-cbon this is the idiomatic way of testing request handlers in Go. If you're skeptical, just google "testing http handlers in golang" and you'll find a page of blogs creating test servers. If you wouldn't mind, please undo the downvotes on both answers, because both are correct ways of testing and people needing help shouldn't be discouraged from reading them. Cheers.

Comment: well, i disagree. kindly. there is a responserecorder along the testserver and it does much better job of providing a lean API to tests HTTP handlers.

Comment: How about adding an answer then?

Comment: if i put an answer i wont even need httptest package ..... I have put comment on OP

Comment: my comment was really strictly speaking about your code.

Comment: like, edit your post i ll remove my downvote, as i missread your stuff.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/YvGUvtn7-G6 you see no http test server. The only thing i am unable to test right now is a input to the html parser that will brek. Maybe with some binary data it will break. This is unclear as HTML is very permissive.

Comment: though for me to remove the downvote, you must edit your post

Comment: got ride of the empty interface it is useless https://play.golang.org/p/UcbC9XirBJs

Comment: turned that into a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68717206/pros-cons-using-two-different-testing-methods